Is there a vimscript command equivalent to ya"?
Depending on the settings, if I ya" then I yank all the text between two double-quotes (including the double quotes).
I am wondering how to create a function with a similar effect, namely a function foo such that given a cursor position and a character return all the text surrounded by the specified character. For example, the following call
var my_text = foo(getcurpos(), '"')

return all the text between the previous " and the next " (including the "").

See :help :normal.

Do you want to return the text, yank it, or something else?

As already written, I want "[...]a similar effect, namely a function foo such that given a cursor position and a character return all the text surrounded by the specified character." FYI: I sorted it out how. I am going to answer my own question.

While it seems to solve your immediate problem with replicating ya", the function in your self-answer is short-sighted for several reasons:

It uses characters as delimiters so it can only be used to mimic text objects that work like that. This means that you will need a completely different logic for other text objects like ip or as.
The a" text object and its cousins skip escaped quotes, as in "foo bar\" baz". That's even more logic to implement.
It is limited by design to inline text objects so, again, adding support for ap or it or a] is going to add even more complexity (and a lot of it).
It can't be made to work with custom and third-party text objects.

This function, on the other hand, effortlessly handles all text objects, even custom and third-party ones, by capitalizing on Vim's own text object mechanism:
function! GetTextObject(textobject)
    " backup the content of register t (arbitrary choice, YMMV)
    let oldreg = getreg("t")

    " silently yank the text covered by whatever text object
    " was given as argument into register t
    execute 'silent normal "ty' .. a:textobject

    " save the content of register t into a variable
    let text = getreg("t")

    " restore register t
    call setreg("t", oldreg)

    " return the content of given text object
    return text
endfunction


Much better! I always forgot get/setreg. In reality, when I am scripting, I tend to avoid using registers.

Here is a possible function that returns the text surrounded by a user-specified character:
def GetSurroundedText(char: string)
    var prev_char_y_pos = searchpos(char, 'bnW')[1]
    var next_char_y_pos = searchpos(char, 'nW')[1] - 2
    var matched_text = getline('.')[prev_char_y_pos : next_char_y_pos]
    return matched_text
enddef

The above function exclude the extremes, but it easy to modify it to include.
